# Initially expanded group in ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, view, expandablelistview

I want my group to be expanded at first time. Then it should behave as usual (collapse/expand after click on indicator)

I cannot found any working solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Loop through all groups and use [expandGroup()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#expandGroup%28int%29) of your ExpandableListView:

```
ExpandableListView expView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expView);
ExpandableRecAdapter expAdapter = new ExpandableRecAdapter(this, expHeaders, expItems);
expView.setAdapter(expAdapter); 

for (int i = 0; i < expAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++)
    expView.expandGroup(i);
```

(or see other StackOverflow questions like this one: [ExpandableListview How to Auto groupExpand - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920185/expandablelistview-how-to-auto-groupexpand-android))

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to API call `exapndGroup`?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#expandGroup(int)