# ExpandableListview How to Auto groupExpand - Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Can anyone please help me how to automatically expand the group in my Expandable Listview, I only have one group. with 5 items. I want to expand it automatically so I don't have to click it. I used groupExpand(0), But its not working :(  .Here is my full code.

```
public class ExpandActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

//String[] actions = new String[] {
//      "",
    //  "Settings",
    //  "About",

    //};
 ListView listView ;
 TextView txtView;


@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.expand);


            ((ExpandableListView) listView).expandGroup(0);

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
        new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                createGroupList(),              // Creating group List.
                R.layout.group_row,             // Group item layout XML.           
                new String[] { "Group Item" },  // the key of group item.
                new int[] { R.id.row_name },    // ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.                   
                createChildList(),              // childData describes second-level entries.
                R.layout.child_row,             // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
                new String[] {"Sub Item"},      // Keys in childData maps to display.
                new int[] { R.id.grp_child}     // Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
            );
        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );       // setting the adapter in the list.

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/* Creating the Hashmap for the row */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createGroupList() {
      ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
      for( int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; ++i ) { // 15 groups........
        HashMap m = new HashMap();
        m.put( "Group Item","Updates"); // the key and it's value.

        result.add( m );
        ((ExpandableListView) listView).expandGroup(0);

      }
      return (List)result;



}

/* creatin the HashMap for the children */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createChildList() {

    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; ++i ) { // this -15 is the number of groups(Here it's fifteen)
      /* each group need each HashMap-Here for each group we have 3 subgroups */
      ArrayList secList = new ArrayList(); 
      for( int n = 0 ; n < 1 ; n++ ) {
        HashMap child = new HashMap();
        child.put( "Sub Item", "DILC");         
        secList.add( child );
      }
     result.add( secList );


     ArrayList secList2 = new ArrayList(); 
  for( int n = 0 ; n < 1 ; n++ ) {
    HashMap child = new HashMap();
    child.put( "Sub Item", "OVRCD");            
    secList.add( child );
  }
 result.add( secList2 );


ArrayList secList3 = new ArrayList(); 
  for( int n = 0 ; n < 1 ; n++ ) {
    HashMap child = new HashMap();
    child.put( "Sub Item", "UPD Information");          
    secList.add( child );
  }
 result.add( secList3 );

ArrayList secList4 = new ArrayList(); 
  for( int n = 0 ; n < 1 ; n++ ) {
    HashMap child = new HashMap();
    child.put( "Sub Item", "UP System");            
    secList.add( child );
  }
 result.add( secList4 );

 ArrayList secList5 = new ArrayList(); 
  for( int n = 0 ; n < 1 ; n++ ) {
    HashMap child = new HashMap();
    child.put( "Sub Item", "All Updates");    
    secList.add( child );
  }
 result.add( secList5 );

    }        
    return result;
}
public void  onContentChanged  () {
    System.out.println("onContentChanged");
    super.onContentChanged();         
}



/* This function is called on each child click */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public boolean onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id) {
     ExpandableListAdapter adap = parent.getExpandableListAdapter();
     int gp = (int) adap.getGroupId(groupPosition);
     int cp = (int) adap.getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);
     if (gp == 0) {
         switch (cp) {
         case 0:
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                 RssTabsActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
              overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_in);
                 break;

            case 1:
             Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                     OVRCD.class);
             startActivity(intent1);
             overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_in);
                break;

            case 2:           
                 Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                         UPDInfo.class);
                 startActivity(intent2);
                 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_in);
                 break;
            case 3:           
             Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                     UPSystem.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_in);
                break;

            case 4:           
                 Intent intent4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                         ALLUPD.class);
                   startActivity(intent4);
                   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_in);
                   break;

             }
         } else if (gp == 1) {
             switch (cp) {
             case 0:
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                     RssTabsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_in);
                 break;
             case 1:
             Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                     RssTabsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_in);
                 break;
             case 2:
                 Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                         RssTabsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_in);
                     break;
             case 3:
                 Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                         RssTabsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_in);
                     break;
             case 4:
                 Intent intent4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                         RssTabsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent4);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_in);
                     break;
             }
         }

         return true;
     };




     @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

         ExpandableListView expView = getExpandableListView();


        ContextThemeWrapper context = null;
        expView.setChildIndicator(context.getResources().getDrawable(
                 R.drawable.arrow_right));
        expView.setChildDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.grey));        

         expView.setDividerHeight(2);


         return parent;

     }




/* This function is called on expansion of the group */
public void  onGroupExpand  (int groupPosition) {
    try{
         System.out.println("Group exapanding Listener => groupPosition = " + groupPosition);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(" groupPosition Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= countChildren; i++)
    listView.expandGroup(i - 1);`

Comment: where should I put that in the code?

Comment: Put it when you want the ExpandableListView to be expanded.

Comment: For example, in the `OnCreate()` method, after the cath block `catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());` ..

Comment: Not working. :( Can you please refer to my code?

Comment: You have the answer ready below :)

Answer (score 1):

do this way:

```
                expList.setAdapter(mNewAdapter);

                for (int i = 0; i < mNewAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++)
                    expList.expandGroup(i);


                expList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                            View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                        return true; // This way the expander cannot be
                                        // collapsed
                    }
                });
```

and:

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/e_lodinfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
         >
    </ExpandableListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `expandGroup()` after you have set the adapter on your listview, not before.